# Как вывести в окно чата список игроков, находящихся на заданной локации в онлайн-игре?

Tags: php

Как сделать окошко в чате Кто есть на этой локации?

Comment: "Кто есть на этой локации"

на какой локации ? Что имеется ввиду ?

Comment: Кто есть онлайн=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У всех локаций есть некий ID. - номер, по которому система отличает локации.
Вот этот айди нужно записывать в базу данных в строку юзера.
Далее,

```
mysql_query('select * from `users` where `location_id`='.$location_id);
```

Если юзер вышел из системы(последнее действие было произведено очень давно, более, чем время сессии), в чате его не показывать.

```
mysql_query('select * from `users` where `location_id`='.$location_id.' and `last_action_time`<'.time()-ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime").');
```

P.S. народу, который минуснул вопрос: имейте совесть, это один из самых интересных вопросов, а главное, в норме, труднореализуемых.
Все дело в том, что заставить юзера нажать на кнопку "выход" почти невозможно(только под угрозой снятия игровых финансов или отбором шмоток), кроме того, крайне сложно отличить когда юзер забыл нажать выход, а когда просто у него проблемы с инетом. 
Так вот, полноценная проверка с точностью до минуты может занимать не один десяток строк и требовать модулей как на серверной стороне, так и на клиентской. ТАК-ТО.

P.P.S. а то, что его задал человек, в норме, задающий весьма простые вопросы - еще ничего не значит. Прочитайте про изобретение автомобильных стеклоочистителей. =)

Comment: Спасибо=) вы как всегда правы=))))

Comment: ух. Хорошая же у вас фантазия. Я от изложения вопрос не понял что имеется ввиду :)

Comment: ой не всегда =) Но стараюсь решать проблему, а не человека. Причины я уже [описывал][1] 

  [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/29447/как-сделать-юнита-на-php-mysql

Comment: @shurik, я довольно долго "работал" тех-админом на форуме, посвященном Гарри Поттеру, а так же поднимал временные доски для браузерных игр и прочего. После этого никакие перлы клиентов не страшны. А тут - тут все понятно, особенно, если просмотреть выборочно хотя бы заголовки предыдущих вопросов.

Comment: @knes, я даже не знаю, какой заголовок и описание подойдет для этого вопроса...

Comment: Например, так :)